# Javascript fetch api get 404 response with golang mux router

Tags: javascript, go, http-status-code-404, fetch-api, mux

I'm trying to post the JSON data to my local server by using Fetch API and Gorilla mux Router.Handle function, But it always return me the 404 status code even though I enter the URL correctly. I managed to run and render my HTML, CSS and JS file in GO local server by entering localhost:3000

Here is my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>
  <body>
     <h1 class="heading">Testing 123</h1>
     <button onclick="Go()">HELLO WORLD</button>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
function Go() {
   var url = "http://localhost:3000/testing";

   data = {};
   data.name = "Jeff";
   data.age = 24
   data.isAlive = true;

   defaultFetchParam = {
       method: 'POST',
       mode: 'cors',
       cache: 'no-cache',
       headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(data),
   };


   fetch(url, defaultFetchParam)
       .then(function (response) {
           console.log("response", response)
           return response.json()
       })
       .then(function (result) {
           console.log("result", result);
       })
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "net/http"
   "github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice"
   "github.com/gorilla/mux"
   "github.com/rs/cors"
)

type People struct {
   Name    string `json:"name"`
   Age     int64  `json:"age"`
   IsAlive bool   `json:"isAlive"`
}

func main() {

   //Init Router
   router := mux.NewRouter()
   router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(rice.MustFindBox("webTest").HTTPBox()))

   router.HandleFunc("/testing", testingFeature).Methods("POST")

   corsOpts := cors.New(cors.Options{
       AllowedOrigins:     []string{"*"},
       AllowedMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT"},
       AllowCredentials:   true,
       AllowedHeaders:     []string{"Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"},
       OptionsPassthrough: true,
   })

   handler := corsOpts.Handler(router)
   http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handler)
  }

func testingFeature(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   var people People
   getInfo := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&people)
   fmt.Println("getInfo", getInfo)
   w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
   json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(getInfo)
}
```

Comment: is because of PathPrefix which creates a new route at `/` you can use `router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(rice.MustFindBox("webTest").HTTPBox()))` or `router.PathPrefix("/files")`

Comment: Thanks mate, I able to get the status code of 200 through Postman. But there is one problem here, after I change to `router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(rice.MustFindBox("webTest").HTTPBox()))` my external link file such as style.css and script.js is not functioning anymore.

it stated **its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**

Do you have any idea why? Thank you so much